# How to make select tags editable on mouse hover using knockout js in asp.net MVC/API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I want to make select tags editable on mouse over.
In my view I have few select options. I want to make them editable on mouse hover like this on the picture.

I had success on text fields but options are being a pain. As the options have `Id` and a `Name` property. So it should also keep track of `Id`s when a user makes a selection.

EG:

```
var ViewModel = {
 selectedId = ko.observable(@Model.Id);
 availableOptions = ko.observableArray(@Model.Options); // Options have {id, Name}
}
```

I am a newbie on KO. Anything will be a lot of help.
Thanks

Could not post picture sorry.But you guys get it :-)

Comment: Umm... no. We don't "get it". Are you talking about having a combo box, where the user can either select an existing option or type in an option of their choice? If so, this has nothing to do with Knockout. You'll need a special JavaScript plugin for something like this. There's tons out there; just do a search for "javascript combo box".

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I took your advice and realized what I was trying to do was basically out of scope for my project and simple edit page or modal would suffice. Those javascript page is a treasure thanks for that.